# jquery can we loop a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

why cant this type of loop works? if this function not looped, it works perfectly. i need this code because i have dynamic appended div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var count = 1; count < 10; count++) {
            $('#keranjang').on('keyup', '#tinggikm'+count+', #lebarkm'+count, function(){
            <!-- Ambil nilai !-->
            var tinggi=parseInt($('#tinggikm'+count).val());
            var lebar=parseInt($('#lebarkm'+count).val());
            var harga=(tinggi * lebar) * 1000;

            $('#hargakm'+count).val(format1(harga, "Rp."));
            });
    }
});
```

this is my html from appended jquery

```
countkm = 1;
 countj = 1;
 countp = 1;
$("#somebutton").click(function () {
 var tipe = $( "#selecttipe option:selected" ).val();
  $("#keranjang").append(
                '<div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #0d8b2a; border-radius:10px; width:31%; margin:10px">'+
                    '<p style="font-size:16px; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:700; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; margin-bottom:15px">'+
                    (tipe == "km" ? 'Kaca Mati ' : tipe == "j" ? 'Jendela ' : 'Pintu ')+(tipe == "km" ? countkm : tipe == "j" ? countj : countp)+
                    '</p>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '<label class="control-label">TINGGI (cm)</label>'+
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+
                        (tipe == "Pintu" ? '200' : '100')+
                        '" id="tinggi'+tipe+(tipe == "km" ? countkm : tipe == "j" ? countj : countp)+'">'+
                        '<label class="control-label">LEBAR (cm)</label>'+
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+
                        '100'+
                        '" id="lebar'+tipe+(tipe == "km" ? countkm : tipe == "j" ? countj : countp)+'">'+
                        '<label class="control-label">HARGA</label>'+
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled value="'+
                        '0'+
                        '" id="harga'+tipe+(tipe == "km" ? countkm : tipe == "j" ? countj : countp)+'">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'
                );
                if (tipe == "km"){countkm++;}else if(tipe =="j"){countj++;}else{countp++;};

});
```

and this is my button html to create the div

```
<select style="float:left; width:50%" class="form-control select2me" id="selecttipe" required>
                            <option value="km">Kaca Mati</option>
                            <option value="j">Jendela</option>
                            <option value="p">Pintu</option>
                        </select>
                        <button id="somebutton" style="float:left; margin-left:10px" type="submit" class="btn"> Tambah</button>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Can you share the HTML? I think you don't need loop at all, may be we provide a better solution

Comment: ID must be unique. I'd suggest you to use a unique class on all elements and do `$('.uniqueClass').on(...)`

Comment: `count` is declared outside the keyup callback function. So constructions as `$('#hargakm'+count)` inside the callback, will not refer to the value of 'count' the function was created for. For some cases `$(this)` can solve that problem, but since there are multiple elements some other work around might be better. As stated by Satpal, if you share your HTML, maybe the community can find an alternative solution.

Comment: there is no need to loop an event for dynamic added elements, just do this: $("parent_element").on('event','targeted_element', function(){...})

Comment: @Me.Name so i have dynamic added div which appended in jquery and having auto incremented id for each input field. for each div there are a little math function: input field `tinggikmX * lebarkmX` using keyup function will make a `hargakm` field shows its value.. so how can i simplify the code without looping it or typing it all manually one by one? u can refer to this site : http://primo.co.id/simulator/ . thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good approach to loop for simply attaching an event. You can do it in a better and simpler way using data attributes. I am guessing that you need to attach a `keyup` event on dynamically generated input fields.

Here is what you can do;

1. Assign a unique `id` to every element in you `div` on HTML creation time in your view e.g `id="tinggikm#{i}"` which will render like `id="tinggikm1"`, `id="tinggikm2"`.
2. Then add common class i.e "my_keyup_input" to the input field on which you want to call `keyup` method. IMPORTANT! add a `data` attribute for the unique count like this `data-count="#{i}"` depending your language.
3. Then finally in jQuery you can listen to the event using the class selector, 
   something like this;

   ```
    $(document).ready(function(){

   $('.my_keyup_input').on('keyup',    function(){

     // Lets get the count to uniquely identify our related div elements
     var count = $(this).data('count');

     var tinggi=parseInt($('#tinggikm'+count).val());
     var lebar=parseInt($('#lebarkm'+count).val());
     var harga=(tinggi * lebar) * 1000;

     $('#hargakm'+count).val(format1(harga, "Rp."));
   });
   });
   ```

Comment: sorry i have another problem now, so now i have multiple` '#hargakm'+count` boxes.. on the keyup event, i want all of the active boxes (which is added dynamically) to sum all of the `#hargakm` and place it on a input field which i have created.. how to do that? *please note i have 3 type of input field `#hargakm #hargap #hargaj` thanks a lot..

Comment: If you havve multiple boxes within the same `div` and want to calculate the sum of there values then you can assign them a unique class based on the `div`, e.g `div_input_box_2` and then can call `$('.div_input_box_'+2).each(function(index,element){
 // here you can do your stuff for each element. may be can get value and add it to a sum variable declared outside this function.
})`

Answer (score 0):

What about using id starts with selector instead of looping like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#keranjang').on('keyup', '[id^=tinggikm], [id^=lebarkm]', function() {
    <!-- Ambil nilai !-->
    var tinggi = parseInt($('#tinggikm' + count).val());
    var lebar = parseInt($('#lebarkm' + count).val());
    var harga = (tinggi * lebar) * 1000;
    $('#hargakm' + count).val(format1(harga, "Rp."));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the created html, an option is to capture all keyups and use the containing `.form-group` to find the respective inputs and values. This way no referencing to specific created id's is necessary. There are more effective ways by changing the way the html is created, but the below should work with the current functionality:

```
$('#keranjang').on('keyup', function(e){ //bind on keyup for entire container (no loop)
    var inp = $(e.target), //the input for which the keyup was captured
        grp=inp.closest('.form-group') //the group the input is in
      inputs = grp.find('.form-control'), //all inputs
        lbl = inputs.filter(':disabled'); //the disabled input is the total (if possible: using specific classes for the inputs and labels would be better)
  lbl.val(inputs.not(lbl).toArray().reduce(function(t,i){return t * parseInt(i.value);}, 1000)); //use reduce on the other inputs, to multiply them with each other (with a base of 1000)  
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pz1axt3/)